# When should I Switch In from Stage Table to a SQL OLTP Partitioned Table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, sql-server-2017, archive

I have an OLTP Database with a big table (30M records a day / 400TPS). I want to implement Partitioning & Sliding Window on that table with Monthly Partitions plus a temp Stage-Table.

The time to Switch-Out (Archive) my data is clear for me: 'End of Month' for the Last Month of my window.
**But my problem is when should I Switch-In new data?** Because this a OLTP DB and users needs access to new data (at least after a minutes or so). It's not really a good practice for me to leave the data in Stage-Table & transfer it at the end of month

Also I'm using SQLServer version 2017, could I use a different FG for the Stage-Table other than the one in the main Paritioned-Table to make the Switch-In work?

Answer (score 3):

In OLTP you would rarely, if ever, switch-in partitions for exactly the reasons you state.  Instead consider using Columnstore with compression delay. See [Get started with Columnstore for real-time operational analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/get-started-with-columnstore-for-real-time-operational-analytics?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks @David, to be clear: 1-you mean that on a OLTP DB I shouldn't use Partitioning or Sliding-Window or I could use both but don't have to use Switch-in & insert directly? (I need to take out older than 2 year data)
About the Column-Store scenario(Article), it somehow matched my case, thanks! But needs more space! Could I just use Column-Store Index as my Clustered Index ?

Comment: Partitioning and switching out is fine.